# How to access data from a MMAX2 annotated XML corpus

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I have an annotated corpus for the task of Coreference Resolution. Can you let me know how to extract the data from xml file. I did the following but not work.

```
from lxml import objectify
import pandas as pd

    xml = objectify.parse(open('Dari_Coref_2_coref_level.xml'))
    root = xml.getroot()

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns='markable')

    for i in range(0, 2):
        obj = root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()
        row = dict(zip(['markable'], [obj[0].text]))
        row_s = pd.Series(row)
        row_s.name = i
        df = df.append(row_s)

 print(df)
```

And the structure of my xml file is like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE markables SYSTEM "markables.dtd">
<markables xmlns="www.eml.org/NameSpaces/coref">
<markable id="markable_1" span="word_1..word_4" mentiontype="ne"  
coref_class="set_1"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
<markable id="markable_3" span="word_33..word_34" mentiontype="ne"  
coref_class="set_2"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
<markable id="markable_2" span="word_5..word_9" mentiontype="np"  
coref_class="set_1"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
<markable id="markable_5" span="word_89..word_90" mentiontype="np"  
coref_class="set_3"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
<markable id="markable_4" span="word_35..word_44" mentiontype="np"  
coref_class="set_2"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
<markable id="markable_7" span="word_124..word_126" mentiontype="ne"  
coref_class="set_4"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
<markable id="markable_6" span="word_91..word_95" mentiontype="np"  
coref_class="set_3"  mmax_level="coref"  coreftype="ident" />
</markables>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  At a minimum you need explain in detail what you mean by _"but not work"_, show what you expect to extract, and what is meant by "annotated XML corpus".
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
import lxml.html

with open('Dari_Coref_2_coref_level.xml', 'rb') as file:
    xml = file.read()

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(xml)

#Use Xpath to extract the data you want.
# For example to extract ids of the tag markable, you can do
ids = tree.xpath("//markable/@id")
print(ids) # ['markable_1', 'markable_3', 'markable_2', ...]
```

Xpath Syntax Tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp